# Pandas sum above all possible thresholds

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset with two risk model scores and observations that have a certain amount of value. Something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'segment':['A','A','A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B'],
                      'model1':[9,4,5,2,9,7,7,8,8,5,6,3],
                      'model2':[9,8,2,4,6,8,8,7,7,7,4,4],
                      'dollars':[15,10,-5,-7,6,7,-2,5,7,3,-1,-3]},
                      columns=['segment','model1','model2','dollars'])
print df

   segment  model1  model2  dollars
0        A       9       9       15
1        A       4       8       10
2        A       5       2       -5
3        A       2       4       -7
4        A       9       6        6
5        A       7       8        7
6        A       7       8       -2
7        B       8       7        5
8        B       8       7        7
9        B       5       7        3
10       B       6       4       -1
11       B       3       4       -3
```

My goal is to determine the simultaneous risk model thresholds where value is maximized, i.e. a cutoff like `(model1 >= X) & (model2 >= Y)`. The risk-models are both rank-ordered such that higher numbers are lower risk and generally higher value.

I was able to get the desired output using a loop approach:

```
df_sum = df.groupby(by=['segment','model1','model2'])['dollars'].agg(['sum']).rename(columns={'sum':'dollar_sum'}).reset_index()
df_sum.loc[:,'threshold_sum'] = 0

#this loop works but runs very slowly on my large dataframe
#calculate the sum of dollars for each combination of possible model score thresholds
for row in df_sum.itertuples():
    #subset the original df down to just the observations above the given model scores
    df_temp = df[((df['model1'] >= getattr(row,'model1')) & (df['model2'] >= getattr(row,'model2')) & (df['segment'] == getattr(row,'segment')))]
    #calculate the sum and add it back to the dataframe
    df_sum.loc[row.Index,'threshold_sum'] = df_temp['dollars'].sum()

#show the max value for each segment
print df_sum.loc[df_sum.groupby(by=['segment'])['threshold_sum'].idxmax()]

  segment  model1  model2  dollar_sum  threshold_sum
1       A       4       8          10             30
7       B       5       7           3             15
```

The loop runs incredibly slowly as the size of the dataframe increases. I'm sure there's a faster way to do this (maybe using `cumsum()` or numpy), but I'm stumped on what it is. Does anyone have a better way to do it? Ideally any code would be easily extendable to n-many risk models and would output all possible combinations of `threshold_sum` in case I add other optimization criteria down the road.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do but maybe start with this:  `df['dollar_sum'] = df.groupby(['segment','model1','model2'])['dollars'].transform(sum)` then you can keep everything in the same dataframe at least

Comment: @JohnE thanks for the suggestion. I went ahead and added a few more comments into my code. Which part of my question are you not sure about? I'm happy to provide clarification as needed

Comment: I don't have time now to figure out your code.  I'd suggest simplifying the example and explaining in words what the solution should look like and re-submitting that as a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found a non-loop approach, it requires some re-shaping and `cumsum()`.

```
df['cumsum_dollars'] = df['dollars']
df2 = pd.pivot_table(df,index=['segment','model1','model2'],values=['dollars','cumsum_dollars'],fill_value=0,aggfunc=np.sum)
# descending sort ensures that the cumsum happens in the desired direction
df2 = df2.unstack(fill_value=0).sort_index(ascending=False,axis=0).sort_index(ascending=False,axis=1)
print(df2)

               dollars                  cumsum_dollars                 
model2               9   8   7  6  4  2              9   8   7  6  4  2
segment model1                                                         
B       8            0   0  12  0  0  0              0   0  12  0  0  0
        6            0   0   0  0 -1  0              0   0   0  0 -1  0
        5            0   0   3  0  0  0              0   0   3  0  0  0
        3            0   0   0  0 -3  0              0   0   0  0 -3  0
A       9           15   0   0  6  0  0             15   0   0  6  0  0
        7            0   5   0  0  0  0              0   5   0  0  0  0
        5            0   0   0  0  0 -5              0   0   0  0  0 -5
        4            0  10   0  0  0  0              0  10   0  0  0  0
        2            0   0   0  0 -7  0              0   0   0  0 -7  0
```

From here, take the cumulative sum in both the horizontal and vertical directions using the `axis` parameter of the `cumsum()` function.

```
df2['cumsum_dollars'] = df2['cumsum_dollars'].groupby(level='segment').cumsum(axis=0).cumsum(axis=1)
print(df2)

               dollars                  cumsum_dollars                    
model2               9   8   7  6  4  2              9   8   7   6   4   2
segment model1                                                            
B       8            0   0  12  0  0  0              0   0  12  12  12  12
        6            0   0   0  0 -1  0              0   0  12  12  11  11
        5            0   0   3  0  0  0              0   0  15  15  14  14
        3            0   0   0  0 -3  0              0   0  15  15  11  11
A       9           15   0   0  6  0  0             15  15  15  21  21  21
        7            0   5   0  0  0  0             15  20  20  26  26  26
        5            0   0   0  0  0 -5             15  20  20  26  26  21
        4            0  10   0  0  0  0             15  30  30  36  36  31
        2            0   0   0  0 -7  0             15  30  30  36  29  24
```

With the cumulative sums calculated, shape the dataframe back into how it originally looked and take the max of each group.

```
df3 = df2.stack().reset_index()
print(df3.loc[df3.groupby(by='segment')['cumsum_dollars'].idxmax()])

    segment  model1  model2  cumsum_dollars  dollars
43       A       4       4              36        0
14       B       5       6              15        0
```

These thresholds where there aren't any observations are actually more valuable than picking any of the options that do have data. Note that `idxmax()` returns the first occurrence of the maximum, which is sufficient for my purposes. If you need to break ties, additional filtering/sorting would be be required before calling `idxmax()`.

Answer (score 1):

You'll get some speedup with `apply()`, using your same approach, but I agree with your hunch, there's probably a faster way.
Here's an `apply()` solution:

With `df_sum` as:

```
df_sum = (df.groupby(['segment','model1','model2'])
            .dollars
            .sum()
            .reset_index()
         )

print(df_sum)
  segment  model1  model2  dollars
0       A       2       4       -7
1       A       4       8       10
2       A       5       2       -5
3       A       7       8        5
4       A       9       6        6
5       A       9       9       15
6       B       3       4       -3
7       B       5       7        3
8       B       6       4       -1
9       B       8       7       12
```

`apply` can be combined with `groupby`:

```
def get_threshold_sum(row):
    return (df.loc[(df.segment == row.segment) & 
                   (df.model1 >= row.model1) & 
                   (df.model2 >= row.model2), 
                   ["segment","dollars"]]
              .groupby('segment')
              .sum()
              .dollars
           )

thresholds = df_sum.apply(get_threshold_sum, axis=1)
mask = thresholds.idxmax()

df_sum.loc[mask]
  segment  model1  model2  dollar_sum
1       A       4       8          10
7       B       5       7           3
```

To see all possible thresholds, just print the `thresholds` list.